# How can I set the 'The other domain supports Kerberos AES Encryption' setting programmatically?

Tags: windows, scripting, kerberos, windows-server-2019, trust-relationship

In the GUI (*Active Directory Domains and Trusts* MMC Snap-in (`domain.msc`)), you can set the "The other domain supports Kerberos AES Encryption" setting for a trust relationship:

[image: The other domain supports Kerberos AES Encryption]

I am looking for a way to set this setting programmatically. I already reviewed the [`Install-ADDSDomain`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsdeployment/install-addsdomain) PowerShell cmdlet and also the `netdom TRUST` tool, but both do not seem to include an option to set the *Kerberos AES encryption* setting.

Can someone tell me, how I can set this setting programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [`ksetup`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ksetup):

```
ksetup /setenctypeattr <THE_OTHER_DOMAIN> AES128-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96 AES256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
```

See also [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/unsupported-etype-error-accessing-trusted-domain#method-1-configure-the-trust-to-support-aes128-and-aes-256-encryption-in-addition-to-rc4-encryption). Be aware where you execute this command for which domain. You can only use it to set the encryption types for *the other domain*. So if you are on a DC of `child.contoso.com`, you can issue:

```
ksetup /setenctypeattr contoso.com AES128-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96 AES256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
```

If you are on a DC of `contoso.com`, you can issue:

```
ksetup /setenctypeattr child.contoso.com AES128-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96 AES256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
```

Other combinations are not possible and you may face the following problems:

- [Failed /SetEncTypeAttr : 0xc0000034](https://serverfault.com/q/811374/536173)
- [ksetup - Failed /GetEncTypeAttr : 0xc0000034](https://serverfault.com/q/1099096/536173)